# WPF XAML Binding Resources Opacity

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, opacity, resourcedictionary

I want to have several different SolidColorBrushes that are different colors, but should all have the same opacity (based off of the opacity that is returned by the converter in x:Name="numCol". That way I don't need to calculate the opacity for each SolidColorBrush. From tutorials I've read online, I would think this would work, but it doesn't.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

        <local:OpacityConverter x:Key="OpacityConverterKey" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Name="numCol" x:Key="numFG" Color="Magenta" Opacity="{Binding Distance, Converter={StaticResource OpacityConverterKey}}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="distFG" Color="Lime" Opacity="{Binding ElementName=numCol, Path=Opacity}" />

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

The first brush works fine, but the second brush doesn't take on the firsts opacity.
Any ideas how to accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: x:Name is only relevant if the element is part of the visual tree (or a naming scope to be precise). You would have to apply the converter to each brush. x:Key is the only valid identifier inside a ResourceDictionary (it's the dictionary key).

Comment: System brushes are a static. You could consider your own static if you want a bunch of your own brushes you will manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is enabling the Opacity override as I understood it:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:OpacityConverter x:Key="OpacityConverterKey" />
            <local:ColorOpacityConverter x:Key="ColorOpacityConverter" />
            <SolidColorBrush  x:Key="numFG" Color="Magenta" Opacity="{Binding Distance , Converter={StaticResource OpacityConverterKey}}"  />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="distFG" Color="Lime"  />
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <local:MainViewModel/>
        </Grid.DataContext>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" >
            <TextBlock.Background >
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ColorOpacityConverter}">
                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource distFG}" Path="Color"/>
                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource numFG}" Path="Opacity"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Background>
            </TextBlock>
        <Slider Grid.Row="1" Value="{Binding Distance,Mode=TwoWay}" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"/>

    </Grid>
```

The ColorOpacityConverter takes the color from one resource and the Opacity from a second resource and combine the two.

```
public class ColorOpacityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType,
               object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            System.Windows.Media.Color color  = (System.Windows.Media.Color) values[0] ;
            double opacity = (double)values[1];
            SolidColorBrush solidcolorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(color);
            solidcolorBrush.Opacity =(double) opacity;
            return solidcolorBrush;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetType,
               object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
```